# Moving animations between computers

Tags: animation, rigging

I created a run cycle with Blender 2.72b on one computer, saved the dope sheet progress. I opened it on another computer and some parts of the animation are deformed.

Is there any way to save it properly to use on other computers?
How can I open it on separate computers, And save all data?

[image: screen shot of blender]

Comment: Have you got the same version on the other computer?

Comment: No on the othercomputer there was 2.72 not 2.72b. Now it moving nicely. Thanks for your help

Comment: Awesome! , Could you give my answer a check to let everyone know it works please ?

i sound like a begger XD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have the same versions on each computer, otherwise bugs will occur due to properties that are not imported in earlier versions.

Answer (score 3):

Check in the user preferences the Menu: File/*Auto Execution* option, the rigify rig uses drivers which are disabled by default.

[image]

Comment: Yes that was checked.